# problem with customized destination path

Tags: installshield

during installation i'm giving an option to user to change the default installation dir. Once this is done, installation goes fine and installs in the user specific location. But when i use INSTALLDIR to modify few registry entries, INSTALLDIR is having old, default values but not the user specified. This is happening to only one package and i couldn't find the reason.
Any help will save my time. 
i use installshield 12 on win2k3 x86.
~calvin

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `TARGETDIR` property instead of `INSTALLDIR`, or set the value to `TARGETDIR` when the user begins to install, and then use `TARGETDIR` when setting the registry values.